# How to detect scroll position of ListView in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm using `ListView` widget to show items as a list. In a window three, items viewing must the middle item place in the middle.

So how can I detect position of `ListView` when scrolling stop?

How to detect ListView Scrolling stopped?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I used *`NotificationListener`* that is a widget that listens for notifications bubbling up the tree. Then use *`ScrollEndNotification`*, which indicates that scrolling has stopped.

For scroll position I used `_scrollController` that type is *`ScrollController`*.

```
NotificationListener(
  child: ListView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    children: ...
  ),
  onNotification: (t) {
    if (t is ScrollEndNotification) {
      print(_scrollController.position.pixels);
    }
    //How many pixels scrolled from pervious frame
    print(t.scrollDelta);

    //List scroll position
    print(t.metrics.pixels);
  },
),
```

Comment: where you place these codes, inside ListView (ui) or at bloc ?

Comment: child: new NotificationListener(

Comment: For users in 2021, there is a shorter way to do so (see my answer) :)

Comment: How do I detect a bottom `ScrollEndNotification` only?

Comment: how i scroll horizontal listview only when items are inside of screen(not visible).. i want listview to scroll only when carousel changes and when items are inside of screen that are not visible

Answer (score 39):

majidfathi69's answer is good, but you don't need to add a controller to the list:
(Change `ScrollUpdateNotification` to `ScrollEndNotification` when you only want to be notified when scroll ends.)

```
NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>(
  child: ListView(
    children: ...
  ),
  onNotification: (notification) {
    //How many pixels scrolled from pervious frame
    print(notification.scrollDelta);

    //List scroll position
    print(notification.metrics.pixels);
  },
),
```

Answer (score 22):

The `NotificationListener` now accepts a type argument which makes the code shorter :)

```
NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
  child: ListView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    children: ...
  ),
  onNotification: (notification) {
    print(_scrollController.position.pixels);
    // Return true to cancel the notification bubbling. Return false (or null) to
    // allow the notification to continue to be dispatched to further ancestors.
    return true;
  },
),
```

Comment: With `NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>`, i believe you no longer need `_scrollController` for other than printing the pixel.

Answer (score 17):

You can also achieve this functionality with the following steps

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  YourPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YourPageState createState() => _YourPageState();
}

class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {

  ScrollController _scrollController;
  double _scrollPosition;

  _scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      _scrollPosition = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Position $_scrollPosition pixels'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          itemCount: 200,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.mood),
              title: Text('Item: $index'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to detect the scroll position of your `ListView`, you can simply use this;

`Scrollable.of(context).position.pixels`

Comment: How to detect ListView Scrolling stopped?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @seddiq-sorush answer, you can compare the current position to `_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent` and see if the list is at the bottom

Comment: is it tested on horizontal list also?

Answer (score 3):

https://coflutter.com/flutter-check-if-the-listview-reaches-the-top-or-the-bottom/ Source

If some want to Detect the bottom of a listview then use this way

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
 onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
 if (notification.metrics.atEdge) {
    if (notification.metrics.pixels == 0) {
      print('At top');
    } else {
      print('At bottom');
    }
}
return true;
},
child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
  return YourItemWidget;
})
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say You can easily detect Scroll Position by

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      var _currectScrollPosition = _scrollController.position.pixels;//this is the line
    });
  }
```

but If you are going to call setState in addListener() ; It is okay, but this will cause to rebuild your entire build(context). This is not a good practice for Animations specially.

What I would recommand is to seprate your scrolling widget into a seprate StatefulWidget , Then get the sate of that widget by calling

```
  _yourScrollableWidgetKey.currentState?.controller.addListener(() {
      //code.......
      setState(() {});
    });
```

Note: Set a GlobalKey, and assign to your StatFulWidget.

```
  final _yourScrollableWidgetKey = GlobalKey<_YourScrollAbleWidget>();
  StackedPositionedAnimated(
    key: _yourScrollableWidgetKey,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
class NotificationListenerListviewscroolller extends StatelessWidget {
  NotificationListenerListviewscroolller({super.key});


  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Grid List';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),

      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
          print('inside the onNotification');
          if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.reverse) {
            print('scrolled down');
            //the setState function
          } else if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
              ScrollDirection.forward) {
            print('scrolled up');
            //setState function
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: ListView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          // This next line does the trick.
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 200.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 160.0,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```