# Good use of FetchMore GQL for infinite scroll pagination ListView with Flutter

Tags: flutter, graphql

I'm trying to create a ListView of elements comming from a GraphQL API with [graphql-flutter](https://github.com/zino-app/graphql-flutter) library.

The build of the first page is OK. Then when I start to scroll, the result will be good, my ListView show the second page, then third ect ... correctly.

The problem is, from the second page loading, there is a problem. FetchMore function seems to build multiple request at each page loading. It's like all previous page ever load are load again, more and more.

Strangely as I said, the result of the displayed list is correct for several pages, then suddenly the list loops back from a previous page, then resumes further ...

This is my Query widget:

```
Query(
  options: QueryOptions(
    document: gql(getHistory),
    variables: <String, dynamic>{
      'pubkey': this.pubkey,
      'number': nRepositories,
      'cursor': null
    },
  ),
  builder: (QueryResult result, {refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}) {
    if (result.isLoading && result.data == null) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }

    if (result.hasException) {
      return Text('\nErrors: \n  ' + result.exception.toString());
    }

    if (result.data == null && result.exception.toString() == null) {
      return const Text('Both data and errors are null');
    }

    final List<dynamic> blockchainTX =
        (result.data['txsHistoryBc']['both']['edges'] as List<dynamic>);

    final Map pageInfo =
        result.data['txsHistoryBc']['both']['pageInfo'];

    final String fetchMoreCursor =
        pageInfo['endCursor'];

    FetchMoreOptions opts = FetchMoreOptions(
      variables: {'cursor': fetchMoreCursor},
      updateQuery: (previousResultData, fetchMoreResultData) {
        final List<dynamic> repos = [
          ...previousResultData['txsHistoryBc']['both']['edges']
              as List<dynamic>,
          ...fetchMoreResultData['txsHistoryBc']['both']['edges']
              as List<dynamic>
        ];

        fetchMoreResultData['txsHistoryBc']['both']['edges'] = repos;
        return fetchMoreResultData;
      },
    );

    _scrollController
      ..addListener(() {
        if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
          if (!result.isLoading) {
            print(
                "DEBUG fetchMoreCursor in scrollController: $fetchMoreCursor");
            fetchMore(opts);
          }
        }
      });

    print(
        "###### DEBUG Parse blockchainTX list. Cursor: $fetchMoreCursor ######");
    List _transBC = parseHistory(blockchainTX);

    return Expanded(
      child: HistoryListView(
          scrollController: _scrollController,
          transBC: _transBC,
          historyData: result),
    );
  },
),
```

Then the Widget `HistoryListView` build the list from `transBC` data.
This is the print result of `DEBUG` lines *(see the code above)* for just one page loading, from  the start of the app:

```
I/flutter ( 8745): ###### DEBUG Parse blockchainTX list. Cursor: 386237:8A98F83A120EF89FC65CF43BEE77068F3DA5734340B7987FA059D582A06934F8 ######
I/flutter ( 8745): DEBUG fetchMoreCursor in scrollController: 386237:8A98F83A120EF89FC65CF43BEE77068F3DA5734340B7987FA059D582A06934F8
I/flutter ( 8745): ###### DEBUG Parse blockchainTX list. Cursor: 386237:8A98F83A120EF89FC65CF43BEE77068F3DA5734340B7987FA059D582A06934F8 ######
I/flutter ( 8745): DEBUG fetchMoreCursor in scrollController: 386237:8A98F83A120EF89FC65CF43BEE77068F3DA5734340B7987FA059D582A06934F8
I/flutter ( 8745): ###### DEBUG Parse blockchainTX list. Cursor: 386237:8A98F83A120EF89FC65CF43BEE77068F3DA5734340B7987FA059D582A06934F8 ######
I/flutter ( 8745): ###### DEBUG Parse blockchainTX list. Cursor: 384695:4BF72317A538FB37F71C0A8D5CC36F319F87B7421260F128EFFF75B9A17C2CC7 ######
I/flutter ( 8745): ###### DEBUG Parse blockchainTX list. Cursor: 384695:4BF72317A538FB37F71C0A8D5CC36F319F87B7421260F128EFFF75B9A17C2CC7 ######
```

Note that the `scrollController` function is executed twice, with the first cursor as the same value.
And the `parseHistory` function is then executed 3 times! I just scrolled to load 1 page here.

I really don't understand this behavior ...
I've been working on it for a week now, if developers of this library could explain it to me that would be fantastic.

I am using version 4.0.0-beta.6 of the `graphql_flutter` library.

---

Edit: This is the UI asociate for this test: [image]

The value of `nRepository` here is `3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem here is that you're calling `_scrollController.addListener()` within the `build` function, so you are adding a listener every time the view rebuilds. This is why all the earlier `fetchMore(opts)` calls are triggered every time `maxScrollExtent` is reached.

You could move your `addListener` call to a more appropriate lifecycle method like `initState`, but I would actually recommend [using a `NotificationListener<ScrollUpdateNotification>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54188385/2234013) which is more declarative and may suite your current code better.

Unrelatedly, you might want to check for an empty "stop" cursor to prevent infinite empty last page requests (though maybe not if your list can grow and your backend accounts for it).

Comment: Thank you, I try to understand where to put my `addListener()` to call `fetchMore(opts)`, or how to use `NotificationListener` ...

Comment: @poka Did you find any solution

Comment: @Shaon Yes, I dont use `addListener` anymore, and use `NotificationListener` widget; like @micimize , as you can see here: https://git.duniter.org/clients/gecko/-/blob/master/lib/screens/history.dart#L168


Everything is working fine this way.

Answer (score 0):

I am using notification listener for capturing scroll reaching to the bottom event and it is working. And if you wanna make sure to keep the scroll position after fetching more, be sure to add key in the listview.

```dart
return NotificationListener(
  onNotification: (t) {
    if (t is ScrollEndNotification && _scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * 0.7) {
       fetchMore(_fetchMoreOptions);
    }
    return true;
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
    key: const PageStorageKey<String>('uniqueString'),
    controller: _scrollController,
    ...
  ),
);
```